# Jquery-load event not firing asp.net button click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i Have  tow  Web page  Home.aspx And  login.aspx ---

**login.aspx SouceCode**

```
<div id="Lbox">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Id" CssClass="lable"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_userId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password" CssClass="lable"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_userPass`enter code here`" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Bt_login" runat="server"  Text="Bt_login" onclick="Bt_login_Click" />
<div>
```

**login.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void Bt_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //code here...... 
        }
```

**home.aspx source code**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#log").click(function () {
                $.blockUI({ message: $($("#Info").load("Login.aspx #Lbox")) });
            });
        });
    </script>

<a id="log">Login</a>  

 <div id="Info"></div>
```

problam is here -  in login.aspx page  **Bt_login_Click**  not  firing

Comment: whats wrong? the ("#log").click  not working on home.aspx   Or the onclick="Bt_login_Click" on home.aspx not working?

Comment: onclick="Bt_login_Click"  in  not  firing  in  home .aspx

Comment: @geek his problem is, not even the event in which he written jquery,  not firing.if it will start firing your code may help him

Comment: @user631704 have you tried putting the break point and checked even the control goes over click event or not jquery is later issue

Comment: @user631704 try a clean build and rebuild your project may it help you

Comment: You're loading the login code which will render some HTML, but the code behind for that OnClick is not associated with home.aspx.  Home.aspx has no knowledge of the Bt_login_Click method.  Why are you loading it as AJAX?  You should just load it as an inline DIV.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, `Bt_login_Click` is not supposed to be called. As you loaded part of HTML into `<div>` by jQuery load method, you have to handle form submit by yourself then.

```
$(function() {

  $('#Bt_login').live('click', function () {
     // you code here
  });

});
```